# Office 2016 license missing - cloned volume licensed application

Tags: windows-10, licensing, microsoft-office

Scenario: Office 2016 Enterprise Plus (volume license version) is installed on a base image of Windows 10, then when cloned onto workstations, they report that Office is missing its license and needs to be repaired (repair fails. requires full uninstall, reinstall)

Does anyone know why Office 2016 volume license edition is corrupted when cloned? It should work fine.

ETA: Application logs show an event ID 1000, faulting application MsiExec.exe, faulting module KERNELBASE.dll, exception code 0xc06d007e.

Also event 11729, Product: Microsoft Office 64-bit components 2016 - configuration failed.

When I change directory to the x86 Office16 path and run cscript ospp.vbs /dstatus, is reports "no installed product keys detected"

ETA2: When a newly-imaged workstation first opens an Office product, a "Configuration" wizard begins to run automatically but then fails, leaving Office without a product key. The base image (before sysprep generalize) does not have this problem though. Office works fine on it before sysprep and cloning.

Comment: is there a reason you do actually activate them? I would put the key in and use a central KMS instance to handle this - also takes care of "stolen" keys - at the end it is a generic public key and the real key on the KMS is never revealed. Heck, you may even do the activation in the active.

Comment: What? We don't activate anything manually. Office should just work automatically on the domain PCs, and normally does. It's just this latest image i created, suddenly laptops are saying that the Office 2016 installed is missing its license.

Comment: @dirtysouth89 Hi, like TomTom is asking, how you preconfigure your office ? KMS, MAK... We miss that detail

Comment: We have KMS and AD-based activation in this domain

Comment: How are you imaging these machines? Are you following this procedure? - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/vlactivation/rearm-an-office-installation-on-an-image-when-using-kms-to-activate

Comment: I've never run "ospprearm.exe" before and there has never been a problem. I image by building Windows 10 in a VM, then running sysprep generalize, then using clonezilla to capture the image.